# Firefox is default but still get WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, testing, capybara

I'm setting up Capybara for the first time and it seems to be calling Chrome instead of Firefox by default.

At first I was getting the webdriver error:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
>               unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515*
>   with associated stacktrace
>   https://pastebin.com/TW5NWJgu

I was able to clear this by adding a `gem 'chromedriver-helper'` and the test now opens with chromium.

I also tried adding this to both spec_helper and rails_helper:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox)
end
```

I was able to confirm that rails was able to successfully call firefox because the following command in rails_helper does successfully launch Firefox (but does not take any further action) when I start the test (as per comments, I later removed this command).

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
end
```

I'm getting the same error on a separate machine and on a different rails app (also didn't have geckodriver set-up on the first pass of Capybara)

My understanding is that Capybara should call Firefox by default. There seems to be a second configuration somewhere that I can't find.  Does anyone have an idea of where I might find the line that is calling chrome?

Comment: Looks like I was too liberal with the instructions for putting geckodriver 'somewhere on my path'.  I had placed it in .rbenv/shims (it was the first item on echo $PATH)

I was able to resolve this by moving the geckodriver into /usr/bin

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox` but you should never be calling `Selenium::WebDriver.for` directly when using Capybara.

Comment: When I opened the computer this morning, the error has come back.  I've removed that line as per your suggestion.

Comment: Can you check the chrome driver version by running chromedriver -v ?

Comment: As per recent update to the question, I'm facing the same issue on 2 machines and 2 separate rails apps.  They both have: ChromeDriver 2.41.578700

Comment: @graial can you send the response of the command chromedriver -v ?

Comment: ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706)

Comment: What about removing `RSpec.configure do |config| driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox end` and just adding `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium` ?

Comment: for all of the last 5 comments:  **RSpec.configure do |config| driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox end** was removed.  **Capybara.default_driver = :selenium** is included.  **Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox)
end**  is included.   I am still getting chromium instead of firefox on 2 separate computers, 2 separate rails apps on each computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the log file you provided we can see that you're using Rails 5.1, RSpec 3.8 and Capybara 2.18.  Since the log also includes "actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/driver.rb" we can tell that you're writing system tests/specs (through rspec-rails).  The driver used by system tests is controlled by the `driven_by` method as documented in the  [RSpec system spec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/system-specs/system-spec) and by default uses the Rails registered `:selenium` driver which is configured to use Chrome.  As documented in the [Rails System Test docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.6/classes/ActionDispatch/SystemTestCase.html) you can switch to Firefox by specifying

```
driven_by :selenium, using: :firefox
```

Additionally, Capybara 2.18 is pretty much obsolete at this point. You probably want to update to the latest version (3.6 as of now) if you plan on using the latest versions of Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be what I was looking for.   after updating rails to 5.1-stable as per your answer here:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/3wpxhrr3-TI.   I'm able to run with the updated Capybara.  However, now I'm hung on a missing 'test_helper' that I can't seem to locate.  I'll try again later today and confirm that this is indeed the correct solution

Comment: @graial I'm pretty sure 'test_helper.rb' should only be required when writing rails system tests using minitest -- Since you're using rspec-rails to write system specs you shouldn't be requiring it anywhere -- If you're not add a stack trace for the error to your question.

Comment: Ok,  Yes I had gotten confused about the the difference between rspec and minitest on first pass at the docs you sent me.  I'm now calling driven_by directly from the block of the rspec system test and it is calling firefox correctly.  Thank you very much for you patience!